# declaration of referenced constant is not found in built-in library and project files

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Hello on the server I'm working on a directory named home.
In an other directory there's the library ffmpeg.

Now I'm trying to use ffmpeg in my "home" directory with php.

This is my code line :

```
<?php ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg  video.mpg ?>
```

I know `"<"` is missing. It is on my PHPstorm codeline.

Unfortunately I can read an error which said declaration of referenced constant is not found in built-in library and project files about ffmpeg.
Does anyone now anything about this?

Comment: Where is code? This is my code line :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run an external command from php. You can do that with the [exec()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function:

```
<?php

exec('ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg');
```

See other [program execution functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) in the PHP manual.